# Encrypting Django User Model Fields

Tags: django, python-2.7, encryption, django-models, cryptography

Is there any way Django provides us to Encrypt all / atleast fields like first_name, last_name, email_id of auth.User model just like how it does encrypts PASSWORD field before storing it into Database ?

---

My Workaround:

I have gone through documentation & few questions on StackOverflow, according to which it would be possible to inherit default BaseUser model & define our own myUser model the way we want, by defining the Custom Character Field which encrypts & decrypts characters.

Problem with this is in my application, I have provided SEARCH option for easy access of fields which are characters. If I encrypt all such Char Fields, it's difficult for me to query for search option.

For example: If ABCD, ABCDE, ABC are strings in database & user wishes to know all such entries which have BC, none of results pop out. Reason is each of ABCD, ABCDE, ABC encrypts to different / unique strings ( I am using AES encryption provided by PyCrypto ). Also BC gets encrypted to some unique string which has no similarity between that of ABCD, ABCDE, ABC ( for obvious reason that I am using AES algorithm with key length as 32 ). And the query I have written like

```
MyModel.objects.filter(first_name__icontains='BC')
```

would not return any result. ( Yes I want search to be not case sensitive ).

[Note: I have added all required methods like "to_python" , "get_db_prep_value" in Custom Field, also tried lookup method. But yeah actual problem is each string gets encrypted to unique characters in AES of same length]

Since I am new to Django, my question may not be that like a Django developer. I would like to know answer for either of above two questions. Unless I get answer I am deadlocked. Thanks in advance, but please be kind to me & answer.

Comment: Something like this? https://github.com/defrex/django-encrypted-fields

Comment: @Bibhas Yes, Keyczar also is one of ways I can encrypt. I am using PyCrypto's AES implementation ( I am ready to break my head & change the code ), Is it possible to query for the text as I have explained in the question ?

Comment: that's not explained in the documentation. You could give it a try. Just implement one field and test.

Comment: As far as I checked, and the way fields are implemented have prefix code & they do depend on length in Keyczar too. Nope doesn't work for queries again.

Comment: The Django extension provide some field for encrypting with Keyczar http://django-extensions.readthedocs.org/en/latest/field_extensions.html

Comment: @Azd325 Seems django-extensions takes care of the things I require, will try now & let you know... Thanks for the info on that

Comment: I took more time to reply back here, as my application much bigger than I thought it to be. No @Azd325 it didn't work well for substring search. Again each string created its own cipher which was unique.

Comment: Why you want to search?

Comment: The application I am building is too large, and too much data centric. It would be of no use if I am not providing search option for any User. EncryptedCharField must also be used for other models not only CustomUser model. I am unable to find a method other than substitution cipher (which is more like giving up), but I need some solution for it :(

Comment: FYI: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/181130/encrypted-database-query

Comment: Mystery, well this can be one of the question for research. Yes @Azd325 thanks for the above link, it answered my questions. Will try to have someother workaround for now, & ofcourse will tell here soon on workaround I followed to have faster retrieval of data as well as meeting up requirements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried a lot, found no useful answers for querying partial matches if fields are encrypted. So I had to do this in Python (Found no other way to do it).

This work around works fine only if database we are working with is small, otherwise it comes with cost of performance.

Query all tuples from database, use python to do partial matches.

```
result = []
temp_result = MyModel.objects.all()
for temp in temp_result:
    if query.lower() in temp.first_name.lower():
        result.append(temp)
```

or something like above. I know this is rude way of Querying, but for the given conditions this was only available solution.